# How can one render Handlebars variables inside a custom helper block?

Tags: handlebars.js, express-handlebars, handlebarshelper

I'm trying to get two Handlebars variables to render inside a custom Handlebars helper I've created.

I'm using the Express.js view engine for handlebars.js, and in my `app.js` have set up a helper to compare equality:

```
const hbs = require('hbs');

app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

hbs.registerHelper('ifEqual', (a, b, options) => {
  if (a === b) {
    return options.fn(this);
  }
  return options.inverse(this);
});
```

My controller passes two variables to the view:

```
res.render('my-view', {
  x: 3,
  y: 3,
});
```

In `my-view.hbs` I'd like to render the variables if they're equal, so I tried:

```
{{#ifEqual x y}}
  foo
  {{x}}
  {{y}}
{{/ifEqual}}
```

The result is only `foo` renders. Why don't `{{x}}` and `{{y}}` render here? Do I need to do this with a partial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your template will not render the values of `x` or `y` from within your `ifEqual` block is because there are no `x` or `y` properties within the context of that block. The reason that these properties are missing from the context is a very simple one: It is because in your call to `registerHelper` you used an Arrow Function Expression to define the Helper function.

[Arrow Functions Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), in addition to a more compact syntax, are different from standard Function Expressions. The important difference in this case is that they do not have their own `this` context.

When you call `registerHelper`, Handlebars will bind the helper callback function to the data context of the template, in this case that would be the Object: `{ x: 3, y: 3 }`. However, this will only work if you use a *regular Function Expression* as your callback and *not* an Arrow Function Expression - as the Arrow Function Expression cannot be dynamically bound to a different `this` context.

This means that you must use a regular function expression as your argument to `registerHelper`:

```
hbs.registerHelper('ifEqual', function (a, b, options) {
    // Function body remains the same.
});
```

To get a better sense of what is wrong, you could `console.log(this)` within your helper using both function expression types and compare the difference.

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/o54sd216/1/) to demonstrate the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I've done this with a different approach:

```
hbs.registerHelper('renderVars', (a, b) => {
  let output;
  if (a === b) {
    output = `foo ${a} ${b}`;
  } else {
    output = 'foo';
  }
  return output;
});
```

Then in my view:

```
{{#renderVars x y}}
{{/renderVars}}
```