# Handlebars custom registerHelper error : not returning anything

Tags: express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars, handlebarshelper

```js
handlebars.registerHelper('isVideo', (val, options) => {
    if (val == 'video') {
        return options.fn(this)
    }
    else {
        return options.inverse(this);
    }
})
```

```html
{{#each content}}
          {{#isVideo this.type}}
           <span>This is showing</span>
           <span>This is a not {{this.video}}</span>
          {{else}}
           <span>This is showing</span>
           <span>This is a not {{this.image}}</span>
          {{/isVideo}}
{{/each}}
```

Why `span` **{{this.video}}** and **{{this.image}}** not return anything. what is error?

Comment: It is because your helper function has the wrong `this`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60888657/3397771

Comment: can we access {{#each content}} data inside custom helper {{#isVideo}}

Comment: Yes, please see the post I linked to.