# handlebars custom helper returns empty paragraphs

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm trying to create custom helper for handlebars which will check if strings are equal, technically it works but doesn't allow me to use json data inside. Here is my helper

```
const rawHtmlTemplate = this.htmlConverterService.convertTemplate(templateData.template)

    const hbsTemplate = handlebars.compile(rawHtmlTemplate)

    const payload = JSON.parse(
      readFileSync(`${dirname(templateData.template)}/example/payload.json`, { encoding: 'utf8' })
    )
    handlebars.registerHelper('if_eq', (p, q, options) => {
      return p == q ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this)
    })

    const htmlContent = hbsTemplate(payload)
```

and here is part in html:

```
 {{#if_eq rawSource.isBackup "YES" }}
        <div class="content-row">
          <p>{{ rawSource.L_backupLocation }}</p>
          <p class="bold-500">{{ rawSource.backupLocation }}</p>
        </div>
      {{/if_eq}}
```

So If I use this with fixed text inside without getting it from payload, it works well so condition is ok, just when I want to continue of getting data from payload, it returns empty paragraphs. It works well with standard conditions like "IF", "Unless" etc

Comment: I believe the issue is due to the fact that you are using an arrow function to register your helper rather than a function expression. The arrow function body has a different `this` value, which means the value sent to `options.fn` and `options.inverse` is not what you want it to be. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60888657/3397771 for a fuller explanation.

Comment: Ah so that was a problem, oki I changed it from arrow function to normal one and it works! Thanks!